# How to implement offline data synchronization on several nodes?

Tags: ros, synchronization, offline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I asked a first question here http://answers.ros.org/question/122901/how-to-implement-offline-data-synchronization/?answer=123036#post-id-123036 but I did not have the right answer of my requirement.

In order to clarify my need, I would like to use the same call graph as in online mode (publish/subscribe mechanism) to do quality test of one algorithm or several. For a better understanding, I draw an example of a ROS nodes architecture (sorry for the link below, my karma is insufficient to publish links):

http://www.dropbox.com/s/tow3fsidlsx4yjg/ROS_Messages_synchronization.png

With this architecture in mind, I want to test the quality of each algorithm for each message. Typically, if the Algorithm 3 is too slow compare to the Algorithm 2, Algorithm2 need to wait the end of the Algorithm 3 process.

Have you already thought about a synchronize solution inside ROS?
Are you going to implement this king of feature, in ROS, in a near future?
Is it impossible to do that in the core?

Nicolas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134276/how-to-implement-offline-data-synchronization-on-several-nodes?/) by [Nicolas Vignard](https://answers.ros.org/users/11166/nicolas-vignard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-02-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Ecto](https://github.com/plasmodic/ecto) is a synchronous processing pipeline that can be tied into ROS. It's aimed primarily at image processing, but I suspect it can be used with other types of data as well.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, this might help you: https://github.com/lrse/batch_ros

---

Originally posted by [Matias](https://answers.ros.org/users/11721/matias/) with karma: 122 on 2018-11-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2